# mysql function return list of data

Tags: mysql

I would like to write a mysql function that takes an integer as input and that function execute a select statements "select id from table_name" then i want that function return the result of select statements.

then

in query i want to do smthing like:

select id,name from table_name where id in (`call function here that returns a list of ids`).

Is that valid in mysql ??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in `MySQL`.

A `MySQL` procedure that returns a resultset cannot be used in a subquery.

If your function is just a number of `SELECT` statements, you can do something like this instead:

```
SELECT  id, name
FROM    mytable1
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable2
        WHERE   value = @myinteger
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable2
        WHERE   value = @myinteger
        UNION ALL
        …
        )
```

or, which is more efficient,

```
SELECT  id, name
FROM    mytable1 t1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable2 t2
        WHERE   t2.id = t1.id
                AND t2.value = @myinteger
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable3 t2
        WHERE   t3.id = t1.id
                AND t3.value = @myinteger
        UNION ALL
        …
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use subqueries in MySql

something like following

```
select id,name from table_name1 
               where id in (select DISTINCT(table_name1_id) from table_name2)
```

Comment: in my case i cant use subquires because the subquery contains union so it work with "in" clause.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a function, you can use a subquery.

E.g.

```
select id,name from table_name where id in (select someIds from othertable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use a Stored Procedure, a UDF or even a subquery.

Have a look:

1. [MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual - Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html)
2. [MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual - Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html)
3. [MySQL Stored Procedures: Part 1](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3525581/MySQL-Stored-Procedures-Part-1.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a function, you can:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func (in_id INT(11), value INT(11)) RETURNS INT(11) DETERMINISTIC 
RETURN in_id IN (SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id = value);
```

and you would call it with this:

```
SELECT id,name from table_name where myfunc(id, 1);
```

It is generally slow because MySQL can't optimize its use, but does the job.